# How to stand up "flat image" to standing like popup book using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css

I want to stand up a flat image using jQuery as if it was lying flat on a table and then stood up vertically on page load like a pop up book...

Does anyone know of any resources to help me or have an idea of a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ (->3D ROTATION->Rotate X)

The following works for me in Chrome 20 http://jsfiddle.net/t9Dty/

HTML:

```
<div class="rotate">
  Hello World
</div>

<a href="#">run it</a>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  padding: 50px;
}

.rotate{
  width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #000000;
    background: #eee; 
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg)
}
```

JS:

```
//set transform origin to y bottom
$('.rotate').css({ transformOrigin: '50% 100%' });

$('a').click(function(){
  $('.rotate').transition({ rotateX: '0deg', perspective: '100px' });
});
​
```

Comment: That kinda works..I have had to hack it a little as it folds in the center of the image so I had to double the height of the image from the bottom and fill it with white space so it appears as it is popping up from the bottom.. I have read the docs and cannot see a way to pop up from the bottom axis.. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That is totally awesome! Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What's the browser support/limitations on this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility (3D Support)